# Spark job fails once a day with java.io.OptionalDataException

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using spark 2.2.0 and running my jobs using YARN on Cloudera. It's a streaming job which takes events from Kafka, filters and enriches them, stores them in ES and then commit offsets back to Kafka. These are the configurations:

### kafka

```
topic-partitions: 5
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=10000
```

### spark

```
num-executors 5 
executor-cores 8
executor-memory 12g 
driver-memory 16g
spark.batch.interval=10
```

### elasticsearch

```
es.bulk.action.count=5000
es.bulk.action.bytes=20
es.bulk.action.flush.interval=30
es.bulk.backoff.policy.interval=1
es.bulk.number.of.retries=0
```

I filter and enrich my events on executors, but then I send them back to driver so that the driver can store them in ES and once gets a reply from ES, can store offsets in Kafka. I tried storing events in ES on executors, but the overall process became very slow and I started getting huge delays. I had to sync and wait for ES to send back a response and then send that response to driver

Here is my code snippet:

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD( // kafka topic
                rdd -> { // runs on driver
                    String batchIdentifier =
                            Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));

                    LOGGER.info("@@ [" + batchIdentifier + "] Starting batch ...");

                    Instant batchStart = Instant.now();

                    List<InsertRequestWrapper> insertRequests =
                            rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex( // kafka partition
                                    (index, eventsIterator) -> { // runs on worker

                                        OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

                                        LOGGER.info(
                                                "@@ Consuming " + offsetRanges[index].count() + " events" + " partition: " + index
                                        );

                                        if (!eventsIterator.hasNext()) {
                                            return Collections.emptyIterator();
                                        }

                                        // get single ES documents
                                        List<SingleEventBaseDocument> eventList = getSingleEventBaseDocuments(eventsIterator);

                                        // build request wrappers
                                        List<InsertRequestWrapper> requestWrapperList = getRequestsToInsert(eventList, offsetRanges[index]);

                                        LOGGER.info(
                                                "@@ Processed " + offsetRanges[index].count() + " events" + " partition: " + index + " list size: " + eventList.size()
                                        );

                                        return requestWrapperList.iterator();
                                    },
                                    true
                            ).collect();

                    elasticSearchRepository.addElasticSearchDocuments(insertRequests);

                    LOGGER.info(
                            "@@ [" + batchIdentifier + "] Finished batch of " + insertRequests.size() + " messages " +
                                    "in " + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - batchStart.toEpochMilli()) + "ms"
                    );
                });

private List<SingleEventBaseDocument> getSingleEventBaseDocuments(final Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> eventsIterator) {
        Iterable<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> iterable = () -> eventsIterator;
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), true)
                .map(this::toEnrichedEvent)
                .filter(this::isValidEvent)
                .map(this::toEventDocument)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

private List<InsertRequestWrapper> getRequestsToInsert(List<SingleEventBaseDocument> list, OffsetRange offsetRange) {
        return list.stream()
                .map(event -> toInsertRequestWrapper(event, offsetRange))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

My job runs fine for almost 1.5 day, but then crashes with the following stack trace:

```
Driver stacktrace: 
2019-10-09 13:16:40,172 WARN org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0 
2019-10-09 13:16:40,172 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler Job 7934 failed: collect at AbstractJob.java:133, took 0.116175 s 
2019-10-09 13:16:40,177 INFO org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler Finished job streaming job 1570627000000 ms.0 from job set of time 1570627000000 ms 
2019-10-09 13:16:40,179 ERROR org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler Error running job streaming job 1570627000000 ms.0 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 7934.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 7934.0 (TID 39681, l-lhr1-hdpwo-806.zanox-live.de, executor 3): java.io.OptionalDataException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1587)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1407)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1966)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1561)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:380)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

## executor log:

```
ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 4.3 in stage 7934.0 (TID 39685)
java.io.OptionalDataException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1587)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1407)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1966)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1561)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:380)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Need executor logs to really know, but its most likely memory related since you are using .collect, or you're doing something with those iterators in the functions you havn't shown us. You shouldn't be using the .collect function, use a library that can write rdd's directly to es for you. Starting point: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

Comment: @soote I have edited my question and added executor stack trace and also the function calls. By its stack trace, it looks like the problem occurred in executors not inside driver. Also, the job ran fine for 1.5 days. It was initially processing 500k events because I wanted to do a bulk import and then the number dropped to 20k. How can driver not handle 20k events when it was handling 500k events in 10 seconds? :/